# How to use javascript in static resources and then to refer in VF Page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, static-resources

This the VF page code :

```
<script>    

              $(document).ready(function() {

            // SUCCESS AJAX CALL, replace "success: false," by:     success : function() { callSuccessFunction() }, 
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine({ 
           });                                  
         }); 

</script>
<script>
          function maskvalidation(){
          var sr=navigator.appName;
        <!-- if(sr!="Microsoft Internet Explorer")-->

                           $.noConflict();        
                          $(function() {
                          $("#CPF_Web_c").mask("999.999.999-99");             
                          }); 
                          $(function() {
                              $("#Phone").mask("9999999999"); 
                              $("#ContactMobile").mask("(99)99999-9999");                         
                          });

        }
</script>
<script>
  function cpfreturn(){


       var strg1=document.getElementById("Endereço").value;
      // var strg2=document.getElementById("Numero").value;

       //document.getElementById("Endereço").value=strg1.concat(strg2);


       var type= document.getElementById('type');
       var subject= type.options[type.selectedIndex].value;



        if(subject=="Information Request")
           {

           document.getElementById('subject').value="Information Request WebForm";

           }
       if(subject=="Complaint")
   {

   document.getElementById('subject').value="Complaint WebForm";


    }
       if(subject=="Service Request")
   {

   document.getElementById('subject').value="Service Request WebForm";


    }
       if(subject=="Other")
   {

   document.getElementById('subject').value="Other WebForm";


    }





    }
</script>
```

Need to do following things :
1 ) I have to use this in static resource.
2) I have to refer this static resource in VF Component
3) I have to refer the component in VF Page

Answer (score 1):

1. Save it and upload it as a static resource
2. In the component add `<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.STATICRESOIRCENAME)}'/>`

if you add it to a nested zip file, you will have to add the path to the `includeScript` and the documentation of the tags has all that information

Comment: My static resource zip file is 'web2caseresources'. In that after extraction,it will go to the folder like web2caseresources-->js-->ce.js


From the above , how can I refer ?